# date function in file which starts on system startup - bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, datetime

I am trying to run a bash script on start up. The aim of the script is to play an mp3 file with the music player mplayer, at a set time (say at 15 past every hour).

My bash script is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

while :
do
    S=$(date)
    T=${S:14:2} #this gives me the minute column of the current time
    if [ $T -eq 15 ]
then
    mplayer path_to_mp3_file
fi
done
```

When I run this bash file from the terminal it works absolutely fine. 
However, when I restart my Linux computer with exactly the same script, it fails to work(this is also the case with other music players such as vlc). The script also works when it **only** contains the `mplayer file_path` command.

I have tried setting a standard program to open the script, the *gnome-terminal.wrapper*.
The way in which I was able to set the program as a start up application is in *menu>Preferences>Startup applications* and add the file to the already existing applications.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 parts to your problem. 1. play the mp3, 2. (presumably only when the user is logged in). For **part 1**, use a `crontab` and have the `cron` daemon run the script at 15 past the hour. You create your crontab file with `crontab -e` (to edit your crontab).  The format of a crontab entry is:

```
* * * * * command_to_execute
| | | | |
| | | | +- day of week  (0-6) (Sunday = 0)
| | | +--- month        (1-12)
| | +----- day of month (1-31)
| +------- hour         (0-23)
+--------- minute       (0-59)
```

In your case you would want:

```
15 * * * * playmymp3.sh
```

**Part 2** In your script you will want to check whether the user is logged in. To only play the music when you are logged in, test that you are logged in with `users`. Something like this in `playmymp3.sh` should work:

```
if grep -q "yourlogin" < <( users ); then
    #play mp3 file
fi
```

Give it a try and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
T=$(date +%M)
```

instead of:

```
S=$(date)
T=${S:14:2} #this gives me the minute column of the current time
```

(note: your script enters in a very fast loop when no sound must be played, I suggest you include a sleep command).

Comment: In that case, when running the script from the terminal, it brings up the error "M: integer expected" in respect to the line with the if statement.

Comment: My apologices, typo mistake, I forgot one %

Comment: That seems to work only when I run it from the terminal, but not when it is supposed to run at start up

Comment: That points more to how you use this script at init than to the script itself. Could be you can edit the original question and explain the usage of the script?

Comment: @Mari0: The `M` is almost certainly coming for a quoting error in how you call `T=$(date +%M)`. Maybe you need to do `T=$(date +\%M)`. Add shell debuging/trace with `set -vx` near the top of your script to see each line execute (its a little confusing at first). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies on my part.

When setting the script as a startup file, I had not noticed that I had to provide an actual command, *bash script_path*, instead of solely the file path.

With this, my problem seems to be solved.